# Where would I place a global utility function in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

When writing an iOS app, where would I place a function that I intend to use from any other file?

For example, a function to convert a NSDate to a relative time string ("5 secs ago"). 
Would I make a class and make these functions all static?

Comment: In Objective-C parlance you don't put "functions" in a class and make them "static". Instead you add "class methods" to the class. Your question is ambiguous because there are also static functions (an unrelated C concept).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, Objective C is built on C- there's nothing wrong with creating a C function if that's what works best depending on the situation. Although, I agree that in general one would more often create a class method for iOS development.

Comment: @JRG-Developer I am under the impression that Ryan talks about the concept of class methods, not static C functions. He just used terminology that is common in other languages but not objc.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Nobody's preventing you from putting all your apps code into plain old C procedures - I guess we're talking about style and best practices here, though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Functions can be placed wherever convenient. If a function or group of functions is likely to be imported in many places, you can declare and implement them in their own .h/.m pair. So for example you might implement your date conversion function in a file named **XYZDateUtilities.m**, and declare it in **XYZDateUtilities.h**.

Declaring functions with the `static` qualifier would limit their scope to the file in which they were declared, so you wouldn't want to do that; in fact you'd want to do the opposite -- declare them as `extern` in the .h file so that they'll be visible in other files.

Answer (score 11):

You have a couple options:

1) If you're extending the behavior of a class (such as the NSDate string conversion method you described), it may work best to simply create a category on said class.

Here's a tutorial on iOS categories:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/objective-c-categories/

**Important Note:**

Categories change a class's behavior (if you override a method) everywhere within the project *whether or not you include the header (.h) file in another specific class's imports*

For this reason, it's generally best to *not* override methods via a category, but instead, to create a subclass if you want to change certain methods.

For adding new methods, however, categories can be very convenient and useful.

2) If you want to create a new class that's imported everywhere, you can create said class and put its header import, i.e. `#import "MyClass.h"`, into your project's `prefix.pch` file (found under the "supporting files" group within the project by default).

Anything that you put into the `prefix.pch` file will be available anywhere within your app. This is also a useful place to put constants (such as strings) or define enums that are used across many classes within the app.

I hope this helps. Let me know if further clarification is needed, and I'll do my best to help.

Cheers!

Comment: I thought the question was about where to place a *function* rather than a method.

Comment: Based on his example, I'd more likely use a class method... although, you're right, the author does allude to creating C functions.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a category. An instance method (not a class method) on `NSDate` would be a perfect way to handle this particular example.

Comment: @noa, you're right, I meant an instance method (not a class method) on a category per the asker's example... ;)

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to create a class for your helper methods and implement all the helpers as class methods.

e.g. **HelperClass.h**

```
+ (NSString *)getFrenchCapital
```

e.g. **HelperClass.m**

```
+ (NSString *)getFrenchCapital
{
    return @"Paris";
}
```

Then import your helper class wherever you need it, and simply call the class methods:

e.g. **Foo.m**

```
#import "HelperClass.h"

...

- (void)logFrenchCapital
{
    NSLog(@"Capital of France: %@", [HelperClass getFrenchCapital]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make all functions static in a class, then alternative is to just define functions in .m file, and extern functions in .h file, just like what you do in C.